# Does .equals on Hashset return true regardless of order?

Tags: java, hashset

For the Hashset in java there is a .equals method comparing elements in each set.
Will this return true regardless of order?

Example, let's say we have one set with elements {a,b,c} and another with elements {b,c,a}

if you use .equals on these two sets will it return true, or does it have to be sorted?

Answer (score 14):

This should return true.
The documentation says :

> Compares the specified object with this set for equality. Returns true
>   if the given object is also a set, the two sets have the same size,
>   and every member of the given set is contained in this set. This
>   ensures that the equals method works properly across different
>   implementations of the Set interface.

Answer (score 12):

## `HashSet` has no order

[Java `HashSet`s are unordered](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) – **they do not have an ordering**. Therefore your question simply cannot be asked as posed. The set `{a,b,c}` is the same as the set `{b,c,a}`. That said, `HashSet` inherit's [`AbstractSet#equals(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) which tells us the following:

> Compares the specified object with this set for equality. Returns `true` if the given object is also a set, the two sets have the same size, and every member of the given set is contained in this set. This ensures that the `equals` method works properly across different implementations of the `Set` interface.

Answer (score 2):

`HashSet` implements the `Set` interface(modeling the mathematical set abstraction), which contains no order information and therefore sort makes no sense in a set. As a result, `equals` in a `Set` only considers the members and disregards the orders of members.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will be true because a Set has no implicit order.

You can apply order to a set by using adding a Comparator, or using a special case of Set, such as TreeSet.

Incidentally, a hashcode is used for fast comparison in a Set. According to the equals contract, any two objects that are considered "equal" must have the same hashcode.

This means a Set only has to fall-back to more time consuming methods in the unlikely event of a hashcode colission.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a `HashSet` is an unordered list of unique elements, meaning the order of the elements has no impact on equality.

Below is a demonstration illustrating this.

```java
import java.util.HashSet;

public class TestHashSet 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        HashSet<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<Integer>() {{
            add(1);
            add(2);
            add(3);
            add(4);
            add(5);
        }};
        HashSet<Integer> set2 = new HashSet<Integer>() {{
            add(3);
            add(1);
            add(5);
            add(4);
            add(2);
        }};
        System.out.println("set1 is equal to set2: " + set1.equals(set2));
    }
}
```

Comment: _"Hash is essentially an unordered list"_ not to mention the minor "element uniqueness" detail.

Comment: @MattBall You're right, i forgot to mention it, I have modified my post to reflect your correction.